# Create arithmetic expression from number using +-/* that equals target

Tags: algorithms, python

For example, you are given the `source` 1234 and the `target` 24. The task is to use the standard arithmetic operators `+-/*` placed within `source`, without changing the order of the digits of `source` to create `target`. In this example the solutions are:

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24 = target
12 + 3 * 4 = 24 = target
```

Another example:

```
target=346
source=8675309
# solution
867 - 530 + 9 = 346
```

My question is what data structures and algorithms should I be thinking about for this problem? I've written a solution to this using Python, but it is terribly naive and brute forces the problem. It creates all possible splits in `source`, and then creates all possible expressions by interleaving every combination of `+-\*` within the split of source.

It takes a LONG time to find this solution:

```
source=314159265358 
target=27182    
# solution
3141 * 5 / 9 * 26 / 5 * 3 - 5 * 8
```

I believe the complexity is `O(2^n)`, where `n` is the number of digits in `source`. After each digit you can split or not.

Code below (note it errors if `source` has a `0`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import combinations
from itertools import product
from sys import argv

def split_number(s):
    """ takes input string number and splits it into strings of separate digits """
    return [_ for _ in s]

def partition_list(aList, indices):
    """ split a list into parts, splitting at the indices """
    indices = list(indices)
    return [aList[a:b] for a, b in zip([0] + indices, indices+[None])]

def create_index_splits(list_len, n):
    """ returns a list of all places to create splits to create n splits in a
    list of len list_len """
    return list(combinations(range(1, list_len), n))

def generate_expression(l, operators):
    """ takes a list of list l and a sequence of operators and creates an
    expression of the intreleaved list and operators """
    expression = [item for pair in zip(l, operators) for item in pair]

    # interleave operands and operators
    return ' '.join(expression + [l[-1]])


def generate_expressions(l):
    """generate all possible combinations of digits splits and operators """
    l = convert_list_ints_to_list_str(l)
    operators = '+/*-'

    # cartesian product of operators
    operator_combinations = product(operators, repeat=len(l) - 1)
    return [generate_expression(l, _) for _ in operator_combinations]


def convert_list_ints_to_list_str(l):
    """converst list of lists of digits to list of numbers """
    return [''.join(map(str, _)) for _ in l]


def find_solutions(a, b):
    l = split_number(a)
    index_splits = [create_index_splits(len(l), _) for _ in range(1, len(l))]
    index_splits = [i for j in index_splits for i in j]
    m = [partition_list(l, _) for _ in index_splits]
    b = int(b)
    expressions = list([generate_expressions(_) for _ in m])
    expressions = [i for j in expressions for i in j]

    return [_ for _ in expressions if eval(_) == b]


def main():
    try:
        a = argv[1]
        b = argv[2]
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        print("invalid args")

    [print(_) for _ in find_solutions(a, b)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To run it do `python thisfile.py [source] [target]`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is a solution that is not exponential in the number of digits. It seems similar to [The subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), but with an even larger search space. In other words, you can't do much better than an exhaustive search.